# making the domain of $z ↦\tan(z)$ injective

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given the following:

- $\sin(z)$ = ($e^i$$^z$ - $e^-$$^i$$^z$)/$2i$
- $\cos(z)$ = ($e^i$$^z$ + $e^-$$^i$$^z$)/$2$
- $\sin(z)\cos(w) - \cos(z)\sin(w) = \sin(z-w)$
- $\sin(z) = 0$ has solution $z = kπ$ for some integer $k$
- $\tan(z) = \tan(w)$ has solution $z = w + kπ$ for some integer $k$
- The natural domain of the function $z ↦ \tan(z)$ is D = {$z∈C|z ≠ (2m+1)π/2$, m∈ Z}

**Question:** Use the above to find and sketch a subset $U$ of $D$ so that:

- the function $f: U ↦ C$ given by $f(z) = tan(z)$ is injective AND
- the set of real numbers {$|z| | z ∈ U$} is *not* bounded above AND
- the set of real numbers {$\arg(z) | z ∈ U$} is equal to [0, π].

--My attempt at this question:

Since $|z|$ is not bounded above, I thought it would be the shaded area outside a circle. Also, since $\arg(z) = [o, π]$ it is only the top half of the circle. I think that covers the last two conditions in the question, however I am not sure. Could someone give me some pointers on how to make $f(z)$ injective? Thanks to anyone that helps. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Is $\tan(x+iy)$ one-to-one on the strip $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2, -\infty<y<\infty$?

Comment: @TCL is the final answer to this question the strip defined by the following:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's restate the requirements on $U$:

- Injectivity:   $U$ does not contain any pair of numbers $z,w$ such that the difference $z-w$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.
- Unboundedness:   $U$ stretches infinitely far away from $0$.
- Argument: (a) $U$ is contained in the closed upper halfplane; and (b) $U$ intersects every half-line $\{re^{i\theta}:r\ge 0\}$ with $0\le \theta \le \pi$.

Argument requirements are easy to satisfy: include a half-disk, such as $\{|z|< 1, \mathrm{Im}\,z\ge 0\}$, in  $U$. And do not include anything below the real line.

Concerning unboundedness, the first thing that comes to mind is an infinite horizontal strip. But that would violate injectivity.

A way to satisfy injectivity is to make $U$ "thin" in the horizontal direction. For example, the domain $ \{-1<\mathrm{Re}\,z<1, \ \mathrm{Im}\,z\ge 0\}$ satisfies the injectivity req (as well as the argument req). Imagine it as an infinitely tall tower.

---

Also, you may want to exclude $0$ from $U$, just to avoid arguing about its argument.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I had just worked out that it was an infinite strip before. Could you just confirm that this answer is correct: $${z=x+iy∈C | −π/2<x<π/2, 0<y<∞, z≠−π/2, z≠0,z≠π/2}$$ Thanks again!

Comment: @JoeS Two things: (a) you don't have to say "$z\ne \pm\pi/2$" because these two points are ruled out by the inequality on $x$.

Comment: @JoeS And (b): since your inequality $0<y$ is strict, your set does not have any points with argument equal to $0$ or to $\pi$. According to the problem, it should. Changing the inequality to $0\le y<\infty$ would fix that.  (The set will not be open, but nobody said it has to be open).

Comment: ok thanks. I have two more things I would like to confirm if you don't mind. Firstly, if I mad the x restriction $−π/2≤x<π/2$ would that still be injective? And secondly, why should we exclude the point $z=0$?

Comment: @JoeS Yes, injectivity would still be OK, but you'd have to be careful not to allow $z=\pi/2$ (that is, the number with $y=0$) in your domain. ¶ Why exclude $z=0$? You are asked to make sure that $\{\arg(z)|z\in U\}$ is equal to $[0, \pi]$. If $U$ contains $0$, then it's not clear what $\{\arg(z)|z\in U\}$ even means, since $\arg (0)$ is undefined. You could  argue that this is not a problem, because  $\{\arg(z)|z\in U\}$  means collecting the values of $\arg$  at the points of $U$ where it is defined... but it's easier to just drop $0$ from $U$.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it!